# Gulp-sourcemaps not creating a sourcemap file?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I'm trying to get Gulp sourcemaps to write files, but I can't see these files anywhere. If any new files were created in the working tree, I would see them in `git status`, but nothing no new files to be found.

Below is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    minify = require('gulp-minify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('js', function() {

    return gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(concat('all.js'))
            .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'));
});
```

Is this correct usage? From the examples I've seen elsewhere, this should be OK. I also see that these plugins are compatable with sourcemaps: https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/wiki/Plugins-with-gulp-sourcemaps-support

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the `sourcemaps.write()` method the way you do appends a source maps line to the `all.js` file. If you want to write external source map files, you'll need to pass the path to the `sourcemaps.write()` method:

```
sourcemaps.write('../maps')
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps

Comment: How can I make it save the sourcemaps files next to the minied files? So all.js.map is in same folder as ./public/js/all.js... ?

Comment: @olefrank sourcemaps.write('.')

Comment: I'm doing exactly this and source maps are still not written, any idea why?

Comment: @szx Did you figure it out?  My code is identical to everyone else's and I'm not getting a sourcemap.

Comment: If you made changes to your gulpfile, try stopping and restarting it.  You might expect the updates to be picked up by your watches, but it won't.